# Magento 1.6.2 can't reindex product prices

Tags: magento, indexing

Dear community i am in need of your help.

Spending to much time on a problem that looks quite easy to fix. Can't reindex the pricing. Prices will change on productview page but not on the categorie view.

The error only effects the category view price of configeruble products.

I did:

- Use magento-cleanup.php
- Delete all stores
- Delete all pruducts
- Repeare the database (php myadmin)

Tried to find the database repair tool but it seems not to be available anymore from the magento site???

Below the exception log:

2012-03-31T12:02:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Trace:

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)


#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)


#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)

#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)


#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Indexer\Price\Default.php(278): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')


#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Downloadable\Model\Resource\Indexer\Price.php(47): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->_prepareFinalPriceData()


#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Indexer\Price.php(381): Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()


#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Indexer\Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()


#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(207): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(253): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()


#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Index\controllers\Adminhtml\ProcessController.php(124): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()


#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(420): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()


#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')


#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()


#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)


#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')


#18 {main}
```

Can somebody shed some light on this?

THX!

Comment: The db repair tool can be downloaded here: http://www.magentocommerce.ro/download/

Comment: try `php /your-magento-path/shell/indexer.php info` from a CLI, what does it return?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was tricky for me, I gave a try to Magento 1.7 yesterday and some additional columns have been added after upgrade (`group_price` especially). I switched to 1.6.2 because of several bugs but columns was still here. So I had to delete created columns manually in database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thank you for anwsering! Took me al weekend never was able to solve ... Just restored an old backup and took the loss...

Answer (score 0):

I’ve upgraded a couple of Magento CE (1.4) to Magento EE (1.11) using the traditional (and effective) way. But I found that there was an important issue when reindexing prices that prevented Magento from doing it.

Reading this post on Magento Boards I found that the problem (in my case) was related to an error with the catalog_product_entity_tier_price table where some of the entries were related to products that didn’t exist anymore. This was the actual error and when trying to reindex product prices, Magento would throw this message:

```
There was a problem with reindexing process.
```

How to solve it

So you want to solve this. You have to delete all the entries on the catalog_product_entity_tier_price table that are related to a product that doesn’t exist anymore. You can do it manually or you can use the following script I created. It’s really easy to use.

```
[download from here][1]
```

In that file you’ll find:

```
The script: clean_tier_prices.php
A library to connect in a really easy way to the db
```

Follow this steps:

```
Make a copy of your database (just in case)
Uncompress the zip file in your magento base directory
Edit the lib/db.php file and put there your connection settings (db user, user pass and db)
Open the browser and go to http://yourmagentopath.com/clean_tier_prices.php
You’ll see wich references have been deleted from the catalog_product_entity_tier_price table
Try reindexing again in your Magento backoffice
```

Important note: You use this script at your own risk. Make a copy of your database before applying it. If you improve this, please share it with me and the rest of the world!
[download from here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/120126/clean_tier_prices.zip)